# Unexpected character after continuation character

Tags: python, string

I am new to working with Python, and seem to be having an issue that no matter what I search, and no matter what I try, still presists.

I am trying to execute a system command using the `exec` function.

I have tried the following:

```
exec("/usr/sbin/something --arg")
```

Which returns invalid syntax with a cursor on the first `/`

I have tried

```
exec("\\usr\\sbin\\something --arg")
```

Which returns unexpected character after line continuation character and a cursor on the last character of my argument `g` in this case.

I have been searching for a solution for the last hour, and nothing has helped. How can I simply execute this command without an error being thrown?

Yes, my line endings are correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`exec` is used to execute *Python code* that is represented as a string or code object.  From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec):

> `exec(object[, globals[, locals]])`
>
> This function supports dynamic execution of Python code. `object` must be either a string or a code object. If it is a string, the string is parsed as a suite of Python statements which is then executed (unless a syntax error occurs).

To execute a system command, you can use [`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system):

```
import os
os.system("/usr/sbin/something --arg")
```

Comment: :/ Really... Wish I had known that sooner... :D Thanks! *Edit* It worked, I will accept when I can.

Answer (score -3):

Maybe try putting an `r` in front of the string so it reads `exec(r"\\usr\\sbin\\something --arg")`

Comment: I actually tried using both `r` and `R`. No changes in the errors.

Comment: Placing an `r` before a string literal makes it a [raw-string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals), which simply means that escape sequences are not processed.  But this is unnecessary in the OP's case because he already escaped all of his backslashes.